# How to change the color of Dialog box

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog

When i installed my application in different devices Color of dialog box changes Devices to device 
         How can i set the color of Dialog box

Regards,
Kariyachan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some clues on [anddev.org](http://www.anddev.org/custom_theme_dialog___transparent_background-t7300.html). The basic idea is to extend the default theme and use it in your activity. In particular, you will need to extend the Theme.Dialog style.

Answer (score 1):

Can u name the devices that u r using to test?...Probably they might contain a customized Android build so the dialog color changes. You can leave it as it is since your build would use the default style available for a device else try setting styles that will avoid this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Use activity as a dialog by setting dialog theme to it. Then you can inflate your own layout with your own background and colors.

Answer (score 1):

Change color of DialogBox and do lot more with `AlertDialog`.

**What you have to do:**

> When `AlertDialog` is visible on your screen, `OnShowListener` is called. So, by adding `dialog.setOnShowListener(this)` you will be able to customize your `AlertDialog`.

**Code:**

```
// Create AlertDialog
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(context1);
    adb.setTitle(context1.getString(R.string.app_name))
    .setMessage(message)
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
});
AlertDialog dialog = adb.create();

// Make some UI changes for AlertDialog
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {

        // Add or create your own background drawable for AlertDialog window
        Window view = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getWindow();
        view.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);

        // Customize POSITIVE, NEGATIVE and NEUTRAL buttons.
        Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        positiveButton.setTextColor(context1.getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));
        positiveButton.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        positiveButton.invalidate();

        Button negativeButton = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        negativeButton.setTextColor(context1.getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));
        negativeButton.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        negativeButton.invalidate();

        Button neutralButton = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
        neutralButton.setTextColor(context1.getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));
        neutralButton.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        neutralButton.invalidate();
    }
});
```